# Is there a way to create an auto-incrementing Guid Primary Key in an Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, guid, uuid

I mostly work with sql-server (when I do work with databases) and I am trying to learn pl-sql.

Is there any equivalent to sql-server's auto-generated Guid as primary keys in Oracle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`SYS_GUID()`](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/functions153.htm) to generate a GUID, and use it as DEFAULT value of a column:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  uid_col RAW(32) DEFAULT SYS_GUID(),
  some_val VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

**EDIT**:
See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153815/how-should-i-store-a-guid-in-oracle) for more details.

Comment: You'd also have to code a trigger to ensure that a user- or application-provided RAW(32) wasn't supplied, otherwise you could be subject to key collisions.  Even that isn't completely certain, as triggers can be disabled and some applications (like SQL*Loader in direct path mode) can ignore triggers altogether.

I'm not saying Peter's solution isn't the best availble; just that Oracle doesn't really permit completely system-generated keys.

Comment: This is not enough, you need to add primary key constraint on column `uid_col` to maintain uniqueness of values.

Answer (score -1):

Make char or varchar2 column data type overwise raw to pass future troubles.

Comment: I believe you should provide an explanation how this will help with future troubles.