# What is the equivalent column for sql server uniqueidentifier datatype in oracle database?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle12c, uniqueidentifier, raw

I need to extract uniqueidentifier column data from sqlserver and load it into oracle database. I tried raw(16), but I am getting invalid parameter binding error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I store a GUID in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153815/how-should-i-store-a-guid-in-oracle)

Comment: When I use raw(16) data is not loading and I see below error. 

Invalid parameter binding. Parameter name: System.Guid